# Apple Watch on react-native

Tags: react-native, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I want to get react-native working for the Apple Watch, but I'm not sure where to start

I started reading the code for the iOS implementation to figure out how they did it there.

My question is: are there any resources or guidelines for help to actually implement react-native (do they ever talk about this aspect of it) or do I need to just read through the code and figure it out on my own?

It would be nice if the react-native team made a document on how they got it up and running on iOS (or Android), though they may already have that out there which is what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any advice and/or help

Answer (score 4):

I was looking into this, too. I will share my findings.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/685#issuecomment-89795858) from the React Native team back in 2015, the team doesn't have resources to support it, yet.

> Right now, we're focused on normal iOS and Android. We still a very small team and don't have the resources to target a different support right now. However, we open sourced React Native in the hope that we get help from the community to build those :)

Someone tried to [build one](http://devpost.com/software/react-native-for-apple-watch) with a lot of reverse engineering, but there are still unsolved issues causing crashes.

Comment: I understand. And the point is: it is possible. 
I think in the videos they post from their conferences they posted enough information about the implementation for us [the community] to learn about how to implement it - we just have to take the time to learn how they did it at a high level for us to do the same for the Apple Watch. Maybe. But yeah content to do this would help or at least places to go as a good reference.